# Way to set deep property directly

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'd like to set a variable `user.stackoverflow.name` and that's exactly what I'd like to create it with. Is it possible I can create a deep property with the full variable? I know of an [npm module dotty](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotty) that allow you to set a deep property with a string like this.

```
dotty.put(user, "stackoverflow.name", "thomas")
```

I'd really like to be able to set a deep property like this.

```
user.stackoverflow.name = "thomas"
```

or

```
createDeep(user.stackoverflow.name, "thomas")
```

And if necessary create the nested objects.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have syntax almost like that using ES6 `Proxy` Something like this should do the trick.

```
function deep(obj) {
  const has = ({}).hasOwnProperty.bind(obj);

  return Proxy.create({
    get: function(_, name) {
      return deep(has(name) ? obj[name]: (obj[name] = {}));
    },
    set: function(_, name, value) {
      obj[name] = value;
    }
  })
}

var user = {};

deep(user).stackoverflow.name = 'test';

deep(user).stackoverflow.site.url = 'http';

console.log(user);
```

But you'll need `--harmony-proxies` flag to be on.

```
node --harmony-proxies index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for global variables:

```js
function createDeep(name, value) {
  var current = window;
  var fields = name.split('.');
  var suffix = fields[fields.length-1];
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length-1; i++) {
    var curfield = fields[i];
    if (!(curfield in current)) {
      current[curfield] = {};
    }
    current = current[curfield];
  }
  current[suffix] = value;
  }

createDeep('user.stackoverflow.name', 'thomas');
alert(user.stackoverflow.name);
```

It's not possible to do this if `user` is a local variable, because there's no way to access local variables by name. Global variables are properties of the `window` object.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited @Barmar's code a bit. This will work with local variable:

```js
function setPropertyValue(object, propertyPath, value) {  
  var properties = propertyPath.split('.');
  var currentObject = object;
  var length = properties.length;
  var lastProperty = properties[length-1];

  for (var i = 0; i < length-1; i++)
  {
    var property = properties[i];
    if(!(property in currentObject))
    {
      currentObject[property] = {};
    }
    
    currentObject = currentObject[property];
  }

  currentObject[lastProperty] = value;
}


(function(){
  var user = {};
  setPropertyValue(user, "stackoverflow.name", "thomas");

  alert(user.stackoverflow.name);

})();
```